# My progress bar goes over its specified amount

Tags: vb.net, winforms, progress

I created a simple program called poodle doodle where you just click buttons to add to a progress bar but they could easily crash the program by just going 1 over the max amount but i cant figure out how to stop it from doing that. How can I?

Here's my current code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub poodle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles poodle.Click
    doodle.Visible = True
    poodle.Visible = False
    pdb1.Value = pdb1.Value + 1
End Sub

Private Sub doodle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles doodle.Click
    poodle.Visible = True
    doodle.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub pdb1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pdb1.Click
    If pdb1.Value = 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You Poddled And Doodled To Victory!", "Poodle Doodle Champion")
        pdb1.Value = pdb1.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    pdb1.Maximum = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: check the value before you use it

Comment: You can also call the `PerformStep` method instead of setting the `Value` property explicitly.  When you call `PerformStep`, the `Value` will never go beyond the bounds of the `Minimum` and `Maximum`.  Of course, if you're actually letting the user try to go beyond those bounds then you probably haven't written very good code.  The obvious option seems to be to disable the `Button` that increments the bar if the bar can't actually be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `poodle_Click` method to check that the value is less than 100 like this:

```
Private Sub poodle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles poodle.Click
    doodle.Visible = True
    poodle.Visible = False

    ' This bit
    If pdb1.Value < 100 Then
        pdb1.Value += 1
    End If

End Sub
```

You'll probably want to add other logic to disable the poodle/doodle buttons when the player wins and a way to restart the game.

I'm not sure why you put `pdb1.Value = pdb1.Value = 0` in the `pdb1_Click` method, it should just be `pdb1.Value = 0`.